# Merging datasets only if they exist

Tags: merge, sas

So I'm trying to create a macro in sas and I'm attempting to merge multiple data sets in one data step. This macro also creates a variety of different data sets dynamically so I have no idea what data sets are going to be created and which ones aren't going to. I'm trying to merge four data sets in one data step and I'm trying to only merge the ones that exist and don't merge the ones that don't.

Haven't really tried anything but what I'm trying to do kind of be seen below.

```
DATA Something;
    MERGE Something SomethingElse AnotherThing EXIST(YetAnotherThing)*YetAnotherThing;
RUN;
```

Well obviously that doesn't work because SAS doesn't work like that but I'm trying to do something like that where YetAnotherThing is one of the data sets that I am testing to see whether or not it exists and to merge it to Something if it does.

Comment: Did you try this ?

http://support.sas.com/kb/24/670.html

Comment: @Ben If I'm understanding it properly, I know I could do that but what if I have 50 data sets. I'm not going to do 49 merges calling for whether or not the data set exists 49 times. Or is that my only option.

Comment: Do the data sets that need to be merged have any naming conventions or any systematic way of knowing which data sets need to be merged? There are other ways to automatically generate the lists of data sets if there is a common prefix or some pattern to the data set names.

Comment: @Reeza They could have a naming convention that is similar like Something1-Something50 or other variable names like that but I was hoping to be able to do it to a bunch of differently named variables.

Comment: If there's no rule or systemic way to tell the computer what data sets to include besides someone typing them out that's kind of problematic and doesn't lend itself well to automation. You could write a macro that takes the list, checks the existence of each data set and then merges them, but someone still has to type out that list so adding the exist in front doesn't seem that more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
data test1;
do i = 1 to 10;
    val1 = i;
    output;
end;
run;

data test2;
do i = 1 to 10;
    val2 = i*2;
    output;
end;
run;

data test3;
do i = 1 to 10;
    val3 = i*3;
    output;
end;
run;

data test5;
do i = 1 to 10;
    val5 = i*4;
    output;
end;
run;



%macro multi_merge(varlist);
%local j;
data test_merge;
set %scan(&varlist,1);
run;
%put %sysfunc(countw(&varlist));
%if  %sysfunc(countw(&varlist)) > 1 %then %do;
    %do j = 2 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist));
        %if %sysfunc(exist(%scan(&varlist,&j))) %then %do;
            data test_merge;
            merge test_merge %scan(&varlist,&j);
            by i;
            run;
        %end;
    %end;
%end;
%mend;

%multi_merge(test1 test2 test3 test4 test5);
```

Test4 does not exist.

Same thing with no loop:

if you don't want to loop, you can do this:

```
%macro if_exists(varlist);
%if %sysfunc(exist(%scan(&varlist,1))) %then %scan(&varlist,1);
%mend;

data test_merge2;
merge test1
%if_exists(test2)
%if_exists(test3)
%if_exists(test4)
%if_exists(test5)
%if_exists(test6);
by i;
run;
```

Comment: Guess there's no good looking way to do it and you just need a big do loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a systematic naming convention this can be simplified. For example if you have a common prefix it becomes:

```
data want;
merge prefix: ;
run;
```

If they're all in the same library it's also easy. But otherwise you're stuck checking every single name as above.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1. Loop through the list of input datasets, check if each exists, then merge only those that do.
2. At the start of your macro, before you conditionally create each of the potential input datasets, create a dummy dataset with the same name containing no rows or columns. Then when you attempt to merge them, they will always exist, without messing up the output with lots of missing values.

Sample code for creating an empty dataset:

```
data want;
stop;
run;
```